# System restore state [WinAPI - C/C++]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, system, restore

I've tried a lot of ways and searched many time on google about system restore but found no information on this issue. How I can get the status of each volume with WinAPI?

[image: Here my picture, sorry for the inconvenience]

Comment: Most applets in Control Panel have no api for what they do.   Instead they tinker with registry keys and files directly, mostly registry.  Only direct api control you have over system restore is creating and deleting a restore point.  You can typically reverse-engineer the relevant registry key by using SysInternals' Process Monitor and observe what key is changed when you change the setting with the Configure button.  You shouldn't, this might different on another Windows version.

Comment: Yesterday, I was using ProcMon with SystemPropertiesProtection.exe and no additional information, regrettably